# Query MongoDB C#: how can I extract in a BsonDocument the field that results from calling aggregate method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have 2 collections "images" and "user_preff".

In my app:

- "images" contains "file_name" and "data"(byte array)
- "user_preff" contains "username"(user that liked that image) and "file_name"

What I would like to do is to join this collection and I want to display the images that user liked.

I am using this one :

```
var documents = collection.Aggregate().Match(filter).Lookup("images", "file_name", "file_name", "common").As<BsonDocument>().Match(new BsonDocument()).ToList();
```

Now in the field common is what I want. How can I extract that data into another BsonDocument?

Comment: Maybe [Project](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder_Project__1.htm)? The `As<BsonDocument>().Match(new BsonDocument())` is not needed IMHO

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, Projection is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your binary as `BinData`, and read the values with the following code. Projection used to select the `data` column *and* rename the field, if that's needed.

```
string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var db = client.GetDatabase("test");
//var images = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("images");
var userPreff = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("user_preff");
//images.InsertOne(BsonDocument.Parse("{\"file_name\": \"bus.jpg\", \"data\": BinData(0, \"...\")}"));
//userPreff.InsertOne(BsonDocument.Parse("{\"username\": \"ntohl\", \"file_name\": \"bus.jpg\"}"));
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty;
var documents = userPreff.Aggregate().Match(filter).Lookup("images", "file_name", "file_name", "common")
    .Project("{\"imagesOfUser\": \"$common.data\"}").ToCursor();
while (documents.MoveNext())
{
    foreach (BsonDocument bsonDocument in documents.Current)
    {
        foreach (var image in bsonDocument["imagesOfUser"].AsBsonArray)
        {
            byte[] bytes = image.AsBsonBinaryData.Bytes;
        }
    }
}
```

You can get away with a simpler projection if rename is not needed:

```
var documents = userPreff.Aggregate().Match(filter).Lookup("images", "file_name", "file_name", "common")
    .Project("{\"_id\": 0, \"common.data\": 1}").ToCursor();
while (documents.MoveNext())
{
    foreach (BsonDocument bsonDocument in documents.Current)
    {
        foreach (var common in bsonDocument["common"].AsBsonArray)
        {
            byte[] bytes = common["data"].AsBsonBinaryData.Bytes;
        }
    }
}
```